# How to delete records in mysql using csv INFILE method

Tags: mysql, database, csv, large-data, delete-row

I have a massive records to delete in the database i've got the csv file that determines how which records needs to be deleted from the table.

I am trying to use `INFILE` method of sql.

I've previously used this method to insert rows into the database i am also trying to use this method to delete from the table instead of running loop in the python it is because it is very fast.

Table structure

[image]

csv file

```
info|link
info|link
info|link
info|link
info|link
info|link
info|link
info|link
info|link
info|link
info|link
info|link
info|link
```

What i want.

I want to run match the link from csv and link from table and delete that record permanently.

Delete query that i've run.

```
DELETE records DATA LOCAL INFILE '/Users/dharmendra/Desktop/aws/node.js/download/xvideos.com-deleted-full.csv' INTO TABLE csv FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 0 ROWS (link);
```

I've looked for this solution over the internet but i have't got the solution yet.

Comment: if it is mass deletion then try to delete in chunks instead of deleting all at the same time.

Comment: Yes this is an option but i need a sql based solution for better time execution.

Comment: i would suggest making a staging table where you use `LOAD DATA INFILE...` and chunk delete like @AmitVerma suggested but with [common schema](http://shlomi-noach.github.io/common_schema/introduction.html) then you have a complete MySQL based solution when you use [QueryScript](http://shlomi-noach.github.io/common_schema/query_script.html)

Answer (score 0):

Can't do it in a single query.  Try for 3, something like this:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE t (...);
LOAD DATA INFILE INTO t (...)...;
DELETE FROM records JOIN t ON ...;
```

If you will be deleting millions of rows, it will take a long time.  If "time" matters, there are faster ways we can discuss.